# MS Office Shared Add-In: Why are ICustomTaskPaneConsumer.CTPFactoryAvailable and IRibbonExtensibility.GetCustomUI not called?

Tags: .net, ms-office, ribbon, customtaskpane, shared-addin

We're programming a shared add-in for PowerPoint and implement `IRibbonExtensibility` and `ICustomTaskPaneConsumer` in it. The add-in is registered for the individual users by setting the relevant keys and values in HKCU:

- \Software\Microsoft\Office\PowerPoint\Addins\
- \Software\Classes\
- \Software\Classes\CLSID\
- \Software\Classes\TypeLib\
- \Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\
- \Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\
- \Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\TypeLib\

For almost all of ours users it's working flawlessly but for some, the methods `IRibbonExtensibility.GetCustomUI` and `ICustomTaskPaneConsumer.CTPFactoryAvailable` are not called. The methods implementing IDTExtensibility2, however, are all run. Unfortunately, we don't have access to the users' computers and we can't reproduce the behavior on our development or test machines.

Which circumstances could lead to this situation?

Thanks,
Fab